# How to let Spring manage my DLQ JMS connections

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using a DLQ listener to be invoked every minute via Spring scheduling as follows.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=60000)
public void retryQueue() {
 ConnectionFactory cf =
          new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(uname, pwd, brokerName);
      Connection cn = cf.createConnection();
      cn.start();
      Session sess = cn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Destination queue = sess.createQueue(retryQueue);
      MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
 //further message processing here
}
```

Now my question is that every minute a new connection gets made and destroyed. How can I let Spring handle that connection management so that it does not create a connection every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CachingConnectionFactory` to wrap the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` it will also cache the consumer, by default. If you just want the connection, disable consumer caching, or use the super class `SingleConnectionFactory`.

Comment: This only works if the `SingleExceptionStrategy` is created outside of `retryQueue()` (i.e. as a bean).

Comment: @PetterNordlander Can you explain that part more please

Comment: Also I deployed SingleConnectionFactory it resulted in just tipping my NAT ActiveConnectionCount in EC2

Comment: @station I accidentally wrote `SingleExceptionFactory` instead of SingleConnectionFactory, but I guess you figured. Non the less, the `SingleConnectionFactory` must be instanciated once in the code, not every time the `retryQueue` method executes. Otherwise it will function just like an ordinary ConnectionFactory.